# Linear Time Invariant Systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

Give the linear time invariant system:
$$\dot x = Ax + Bu, \quad x(0) = x_0$$
$$y = Cx$$

How would one solve for $x_0$, $y(t)$, or $u(t)$ given 2 of the 3 unknowns?

*Clarity from comments:* Let's say $(A,C)$ is not completely observable as defined by the observability matrix. ie. if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times 3}$ then $\text{rank}(\theta)=2$, for example

For example, say I am looking for $x_0$: therefore, I know $y(t)$ and $u(t)$ which are defined over some closed interval $[0,t]$.

The state output response of an LTI system is simply:
$$x(t) = e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau$$
$$y(t) = Ce^{At}x_0 + \int_0^tCe^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)d\tau$$

Taking the second equation, $y(t)$ and $u(t)$ would be given along with $A,B,C$ and $t$, so do I simply solve for $x_0$? If so, how do you isolate $x_0$? That is, do you multiply by the inverse of $Ce^{At}$ after integrating the last term and moving it to the LHS? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $(A,C)$ completely observable? What is the definition of observabilty?

Comment: Under observability condition - do not forget you may differentiate $y(t)$.

Comment: @copper.hat That's a good hint! Let's say $(A,C)$ is not completely observable as defined by the observability matrix. ie. if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times3}$ then $\text{rank}(\theta) = 2$ for example

Comment: If the system is not co. then it is not possible to uniquely determine the iniital state.

Comment: @copper.hat I get that, so is there a way to determine the initial state corresponding to the observable subspace and then the 'set' of initial conditions w.r.t to unobservable?

Comment: You need to look at the Kalman observability decomposition.

Comment: @copper.hat That makes sense! Thanks! I'd up vote your comments if I wasn't new :) Feel free to place them in an quick answer if you want!

Comment: Glad to be able to help. Good luck.